# Embedded use of gcc on Windows

Tags: gcc

I am trying to use gcc for embedded program generation. The gcc came from the Mingw toolset,
which is the same gcc I use to generate regular applications under Windows. I am trying to
generate a straight binary, located at 0x1000, for use in an embedded i386/32 bit system.
It gets tested under Bochs.

My linker file looks like this:

```
/* a list of files to link */
INPUT(test.o)

/* output format */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("pe-i386")

/* output filename */
/* OUTPUT_FILENAME("test.out") */

/* list of our memory sections */
MEMORY
{
  ram   : o = 0x1000, l = 256k
}

/* place sections */
SECTIONS
{

  /* code and constants */
  .text :
  {
    __text_start = .;
    *(.text)
    *(.strings)
     __text_end = .;
  }  > ram 

  /* initialized data */
  .data :
  {
    __data_start = .;
    *(.data)
    __data_end = .;
  } > ram

  /* uninitialized data */
  .bss :
  {
     __bss_start = . ; 
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
     __bss_end = . ;  
  }  > ram

}
```

Basically, it means concatenate everything to a target address in ram at 0x1000.

If I select any target besides a PE file I get:

Cannot perform PE operations on a non PE file...

Which other messages here say is a known issue with ld on windows. So I perform another
step to create a binary using objcopy, which works fine.

Here are the output sections:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000038  ffc01000  ffc01000  00001000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .rdata        00000010  ffc02000  ffc02000  00002000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .eh_frame     00000038  ffc03000  ffc03000  00003000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
```

So the sections are being aligned on a page frame address (4kb), which I like.
Here is the disassembly of the .text frame:

```
test.pe:     file format pe-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

ffc01000 <_crap>:
ffc01000:       55                      push   ebp
ffc01001:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
ffc01003:       83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
ffc01006:       c7 45 f8 00 20 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x2000
ffc0100d:       c7 45 fc 00 80 0b 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0xb8000
ffc01014:       eb 14                   jmp    ffc0102a <_crap+0x2a> 
ffc01016:       8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
ffc01019:       8a 00                   mov    al,BYTE PTR [eax]
ffc0101b:       66 98                   cbw
ffc0101d:       8b 55 fc                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
ffc01020:       66 89 02                mov    WORD PTR [edx],ax
ffc01023:       83 45 fc 02             add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x2
ffc01027:       ff 45 f8                inc    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
ffc0102a:       83 7d f8 00             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x0
ffc0102e:       75 e6                   jne    ffc01016 <_crap+0x16>
ffc01030:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
ffc01035:       c9                      leave
ffc01036:       c3                      ret
ffc01037:       90                      nop
```

So I have no idea how or why it located the code at 0xffc01000, that is not what I
specified in the linker instruction file.

With the idea that this was some artifact of the PE file format, I tried to select
other output formats like elf, but if I do that I hit the "cannot perform PE operations
on non PE output file" bug.

The questions are:

1. Why does it locate to 0xffc01000? This doesn't appear to make sense even in the context
   of a Windows program.
2. Is there a way to properly locate the program?
3. Do I need to use a i386 gcc build that is not tied to Windows?

Thank you,

Scott Moore

Comment: You should definitely build GCC as a cross-compiler in the first place, before trying to play with such low-level stuff. Read **[Why do I need a Cross Compiler?](http://wiki.osdev.org/Why_do_I_need_a_Cross_Compiler%3F)** and then **[GCC Cross-Compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)**.

Comment: Yes, I read and understand the concepts, thank you. You'll allow me the  luxury of being a bit sad about the need to build a "cross compiler" that targets the same machine that I am running on !

Comment: Well, not exactly. The target would be the same, however the generated binaries would have different layout. For example, you can employ elf format which is awesome for what you're trying to achieve. This way nothing OS-specific would get into your binaries. On the other hand, MinGW by default injects a lot of platform-specific stuff into your binaries, which is impossible to disable. Quite some time ago, I've played with my kernel, and I had success with GCC cross-compiler and elf format. By the way, I used Bochs as well.

Comment: Ok, I started building a gcc image today. I have not done this for a while, like 7 years, and last time I got paid for it. Honestly, I would rather be hit with a stun gun. Really. Thanks for all the good comments.